# How to split strings based on a list of glossaries?

Tags: regex, split, nlp, tokenize

Given a list of glossaries:

```
glossaries = ['USA', '34']
```

The goal is use the items inside the glossaries and split a string using the glossaries as delimiters. E.g. given the string and the glossaries, an `_isolate_glossaries()` function:

```
glossaries = ['USA', '34']
word = '1934USABUSA'
_isolate_glossaries(word, glossaries)
```

should output:

```
['19', '34', 'USA', 'B', 'USA']
```

I've tried:

```
def isolate_glossary(word, glossary):
    print(word, glossary)
    # Check that word == glossary and glossary not in word
    if re.match('^{}$'.format(glossary), word) or not re.search(glossary, word):
        return [word]
    else:
        segments = re.split(r'({})'.format(glossary), word)
        segments, ending = segments[:-1], segments[-1] # Remove the last catch with null string.
        return segments

def _isolate_glossaries(word, glossaries):
    word_segments = [word]
    for gloss in glossaries:
        word_segments = [out_segment
                         for segment in word_segments 
                         for out_segment in isolate_glossary(segment, gloss)] 
    return word_segments
```

It works but it looks a little too convoluted to have so many levels of loop and regex splits taking place. **Is there a better way to split the string based on the glossaries?**

Comment: You should create a regex for split method dynamically sth like `(UDS|34)`. Glossaries items are in a side of an alternation.

Comment: Like this: `re.split('({})'.format('|'.join(glossaries)), word)` ?

Comment: Yes check it here https://ideone.com/JW7OQR

Comment: Thanks @revo! That's a lot clearer than the original functions I've in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split the string by the items in the list, create a regex on the fly including those items separated by a pipe `|` all enclosed in a capturing group (a non-capturing group doesn't include items themselves in the output):

```
list = re.split('({})'.format('|'.join(glossaries)), word);
print ([x for x in list if x]) # filter non-word items
```

See [live demo here](https://ideone.com/JW7OQR)